# How can I adjust the window size of a QDialog to its content?

Tags: c++, qt, scrollbar, qscrollarea

I have a dialog box with a QScrollArea to show an arbitrary amount of checkboxes. How can I make the dialog box adjust its width so that the QScrollArea does not have a horizontal scroll bar (if the content is not extremely wide).

```
std::vector<std::string> vec_strCheckboxLabel;
vec_strCheckboxLabel.push_back("Checkbox 1");
vec_strCheckboxLabel.push_back("Checkbox 2");
vec_strCheckboxLabel.push_back("Checkbox 3 is really long and causes a horizontal scroll bar to appear");
vec_strCheckboxLabel.push_back("Checkbox 4");
vec_strCheckboxLabel.push_back("Checkbox 5");

m_pWidget = new QDialog;
m_pWidget->setWindowTitle("My Dialog");
m_pWidget->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
m_pWidget->setMinimumWidth(400);
QVBoxLayout * pWidgetLayout = new QVBoxLayout(m_pWidget);
QLabel * pLabel = new QLabel("Hello");
pWidgetLayout->addWidget(pLabel);

QHBoxLayout * pTopButtonsLayout = new QHBoxLayout(m_pWidget);
pWidgetLayout->addLayout(pTopButtonsLayout);

QPushButton * pButton;

pButton = new QPushButton("Select all", m_pWidget);
connect(pButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotSelectAll()));
pTopButtonsLayout->addWidget(pButton);

pButton = new QPushButton("Select none", m_pWidget);
connect(pButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotSelectNone()));
pTopButtonsLayout->addWidget(pButton);

// the checkboxes in a scroll area
{
    QFrame * pFrameCheckboxes = new QFrame(m_pWidget);
    QVBoxLayout * pCheckboxesLayout = new QVBoxLayout(pFrameCheckboxes);
    // this frame takes all available space in the QDialog
    pFrameCheckboxes->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);

    for (unsigned int i = 0, iEnd = vec_strCheckboxLabel.size(); i != iEnd; ++i)
    {
        QCheckBox * poCheckBox = new QCheckBox(vec_strCheckboxLabel[i].c_str());
        pCheckboxesLayout->addWidget(poCheckBox);
    }

    // put into scroll area
    QScrollArea * pScrollAreaTheCheckboxes = new QScrollArea(m_pWidget);
    pWidgetLayout->addWidget(pScrollAreaTheCheckboxes);
    pScrollAreaTheCheckboxes->setWidget(pFrameCheckboxes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the scroll area limits its size to take available space by default; it does not *demand* space from the layout. You have to explicitly tell it to change that behavior.

Check out [`QAbstractScrollArea::SizeAdjustPolicy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#SizeAdjustPolicy-enum). You are probably looking for `AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow`, like so:

```
pScrollAreaTheCheckboxes->setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow);
```

Unfortunately, you cannot set different adjust policies for horizontal and vertical aspects, if this is what you are after. Judicious use of `QSizePolicy` and layout settings (e.g. `setStretch()`) can fix this.

**Qt4**
As a workaround for Qt4, check the viewport's `sizeHint()` and set the scroll area's minimum size to that.

```
 pScrollAreaTheCheckboxes->setMinimumSize(pScrollAreaTheCheckboxes->viewport()->sizeHint());
```

Do this after you've initialized all of your checkboxes.

Comment: Good answer. Unfortunately I must use Qt 4.8. Since it's only a dialog, I just need to set the width to something sensible once when it opens. Is there a way to ask the scroll area directly how much width it needs? Maybe I can ask the checkboxes about their width and take the maximum?

Comment: I added the line to the example above, below `pScrollAreaTheCheckboxes->setWidget(pFrameCheckboxes);`, but it does not change anything. Does it work on your machine?

Comment: Did it make the widget wide enough but the scroll bar still appears? Or is it simply still too small?

Comment: It seems to have no effect at all. The width of the dialog does not change, and the scroll bars still appear.